# How do I import a snapshot using docker?

Tags: node, docker, snapshots

I tried to import snapshot but it didn't work.

```
$ ./mainnet.sh snapshot import BMJgBK8rR4gZPaTcj8EN6uu93hU7AVhPM16GsSB14ZMVxoW1iQ1.full 
mainnet: Pulling from tezos/tezos
Digest: sha256:523a8748fc04106501f176e08ac4648523c7cc620b2d206a65a51fea79945992
Status: Image is up to date for tezos/tezos:mainnet
ERROR: Named volume "BMJgBK8rR4gZPaTcj8EN6uu93hU7AVhPM16GsSB14ZMVxoW1iQ1.full:/snapshot:rw" is used in service "importer" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 5):

So the answer is the import will work if you use an absolute path to your snapshot file.
The snapshot filename alone will not work. Nor will a relative path the filename. The correct command will look like this:

```
./mainnet.sh snapshot import /absolute/path/to/snapshotfile/snapshotfile.full
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had the exact same problem. I've filed a bug against it. See [this issue here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/531)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was fixed here: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/531 .